# ImportError: no module named mako.template

Tags: python, macos, mako

This line of code in my foobar.py file:

```
from mako.template import *
```

results in an

> ImportError: No module named mako.template

How can I fix this? Both `help('modules')` and `repr(mako)` in my Python console assures me that the mako module is installed and available.

I'm on a Mac by the way, running Python 2.6 for this particular project.

**As requested, this is the output from running *pip freeze***

- Mako==0.8.1
- MarkupSafe==0.18
- PyYAML==3.10
- wsgiref==0.1.2

**As requested, this is my sys.path**

['', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python26.zip', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/username/env/myProject/Extras/lib/python', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Users/username/env/myProject/lib/python2.6/site-packages']

Comment: It works for me on linux

Comment: You don't happen to have a `mako.py` in the same directory as your `build.py`, do you?

Comment: Yes, this could be a valid reason Amber

Comment: @Amber No, there's only one .py file in that directory.

Comment: Please paste your PYTHONPATH or the output of sys.path, as well as the output of pwd and ls

Comment: no, just echo $PYTHONPATH, but sys.path is the same, no worries

Comment: running 'echo $PYTHONPATH' outputs an empty line

Comment: It's okay, sys.path is what I needed. But unfortunately, it doesn't help. I added an update on my answer, which could also explain the import issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have **template.py** inside your .env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mako directory?

Are you using virtualenv, or have installed mako in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages?

Please paste an output of `pip freeze`

---

Update:

Have you checked if there is no CR/LF or wrong character on this import line?

What is the encoding of your foobar.py file?

```
file -I foobar.py
```

it should contain *utf-8* or *ascii*

Comment: Yes, both template.py and template.pyc are listed there.

Comment: Oh, then there another unexpected behaviour.
What is your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I'm using virtualenv, yes. Hang on, I'll update the question with the output.

Comment: file -I foobar.py gives charset=us-ascii

Comment: Crap, I think I found the problem. The python binary running the foobar.py file wasn't the same as the one I had in my virtual environment. As such the virtualenv python binary had access to all the modules installed to it, but it was never being used. I apologize for being retarded and wasting your time. Thank you very much for trying to help me though. It's fixed now.

Comment: It's fine, glad you found. Because I was running out of ideas ;-)