# Why I got that problems when I run my script?

Tags: python

What is the solution for this error code?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./weevely.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core.terminal import Terminal
  File "/Users/ismailtaibi/Desktop/isdo/scripts/weevely/core/terminal.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core.module import Status
  File "/Users/ismailtaibi/Desktop/isdo/scripts/weevely/core/module.py", line 14, in <module>
    from core.vectorlist import VectorList
  File "/Users/ismailtaibi/Desktop/isdo/scripts/weevely/core/vectorlist.py", line 15, in <module>
    from core.vectors import Os
  File "/Users/ismailtaibi/Desktop/isdo/scripts/weevely/core/vectors.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mako.template import Template
ImportError: No module named mako.template
```

Comment: I'm sure there is, but unless you show the code or contact a psychic you wont get any help here with what you posted

Comment: You don't have `mako` installed correctly.

Comment: you can't expect us to debug "weevely.py" without seeing it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066424/importerror-no-module-named-mako-template

Comment: how can i install mako . i am using mac

Comment: i trying to run weevely.py

Comment: `pip install Mako` on a terminal ?

Comment: i did it, But the same problem :/

Comment: http://www.makotemplates.org/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is self explanatory with a Google search

Here you have a how to install pip if you don`t have it: [How do I install pip on macOS or OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x)

After this type in the terminal:
`pip install Mako`
as stated in the official website: http://www.makotemplates.org/download.html

If this doesn't work you can manually download the Mako package here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Mako/